# circleMarker click not getting called - OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I see that the click event doesn't get called for circleMarker, but does get called for normal Marker. Any help? https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet/issues/19

http://jsfiddle.net/abarik/crk3jrhp/2/

html

```
<div id="map"></div>
```

css

```
#map {
    height: 440px;
}
```

javascript

```
map = L.map('map', {
    center: [7.2, 40.9],
    zoom: 2
});

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: "Map: Tiles Courtesy of MapQuest (OpenStreetMap, CC-BY-SA)",
    subdomains: ["otile1", "otile2", "otile3", "otile4"],
    maxZoom: 12,
    minZoom: 2
}).addTo(map);

var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map);
var popup = new L.Popup();
oms.addListener('click', function(marker) {
  popup.setContent(marker.__name);
  popup.setLatLng(marker.getLatLng());
  map.openPopup(popup);
});

var marker1 = new L.Marker([1, 1]);
marker1.__name = 'marker1'
map.addLayer(marker1);
oms.addMarker(marker1);

var marker2 = new L.Marker([1, 1]);
marker2.__name = 'marker2'
map.addLayer(marker2);
oms.addMarker(marker2);

var marker1 = new L.circleMarker([20, 20]);
marker1.__name = 'cirmarker1'
map.addLayer(marker1);
oms.addMarker(marker1);

var marker2 = new L.circleMarker([20, 20]);
marker2.__name = 'cirmarker2'
map.addLayer(marker2);
oms.addMarker(marker2);
```

Comment: I'm not sure the issue here is the click event.  Looking at your fiddle, the click event is definitely getting called.  The first click event is triggering the OMS marker to spiderfy, a second click will open your popup.  You have an error in the console related to the oms click event, so it's not completing it's job.

Comment: Your issue is already known ... [take a look](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet/issues/13).

Comment: I have tried it and it doesn't work. @Kathy - If you copy the code and try to run locally, you will see what i am talking about. for some reasons, on jsfiddle, the click works because the spider doesn't collapse

Comment: and by the way i am using 0.7.3 leaflet version